# Как удалить несколько символов из строки по индексу python

Tags: python, строки

Мне нужно удалить все символы, до определённого индекса в строке.
Например:
Есть строка  `str = example` и индекс найден при помощи `str.find('m')`.
Как получить `ple`?

Comment: строки нельзя редактировать в питоне, но можно взять и сделать новую. Используйте срезы в этом случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью среза

```
str = 'example'
idx = str.find('m')
out = str[idx + 1:] # это срез [<от индекса + 1>:<до конца строки>]
print(out)
```

```
ple
```